# Macbook startup disk full; GP shows 164GB of 'Miscellaneous used space'

Tags: hard-drive, startup

I can't work on my macbook anymore as it constantly pops up 'startup disk full' I went through every article I could find, cleaning up as much as I could.

I deleted unnecessary backups, do not have any other user accounts, cleared trash, etc etc.

I currently have about 70GB of files I actually need, and now Grand Perspective is showing me I have 164GB of 'Miscellaneous used space'.

What is this space and can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the [this link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/help-misc-used-space.1840396/) on MacRumors that sounds like the same problem you are having. The gist of it seems to be clearing the system cache using this command `sudo rm -r /System/Library/Caches` could help ( assuming that is where the issue lies). You should also be able to hopefully figure out what is using up all the space with this command `sudo du -chxd 1 /` to see what is taking up all the space.

Comment: Thanks Chillie, I can't seem to clear Cache because it won't permit me to do so, even after enterring all the passwords etc.

Comment: You could try adding an f after the -r so it would look like "sudo rm -rf" or maybe try booting from the recovery partition. that way the cache is not in use when trying to delete.